# Find the probability $P(0.5 < X < 5)$

Tags: probability

We select two balls without replacing from a box where there are 7 red balls and 3 green balls.

Be $X$ the random variable denoting the number of selected green balls.

Please compute $P(0.5 < X < 5)$ (if you can explain to me how to do $P(a<X<b)$ in general that will be great).

Any pointers in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure that you need the probability $P(0.5<X<5)$? Because you cannot draw half a green ball. If you are sure that it is correct, then it holds that $P(0.5<X<5)=P(1<X<5)$.

Comment: I am sure. The problem is taken from a PDF file from my professor and I cracking my head trying to solve as many as possible to prepare for an exam.

Comment: @rbm: no-on the right side you need two green balls while on the left you accept one.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes you are right. I was only discussing the issue with the fraction though. But of course you can draw at most 3 green balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $P(a<X<b)=P(X<b)-P(X\leq a)$ (You won't need that here though, this property will especially be useful when dealing with continuous distributions, intuition is handier in this case).

Here, we need $X$ to be at least $0.5$. Since we cannot draw half a green ball, we need $X\geq 1$. Now reason in the following way, which integer numbers satisfy the condition that they are $>0.5$ (here: $\geq 1$) and $<5$? That are $1$, and $2$ (since it impossible to draw more than $2$ green balls, as we have only $2$ trials). This means that we need $P(X=1)+P(X=2)$

$P(0.5<X<5)=P(X=1)+P(X=2)$

Comment: @StefanHansen You are right. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Because we do not replace the first extracted ball is this correct?
$P(X=2) = \frac{3}{10} \times \frac{3}{9}$
and
$P(X=1) = \frac{3}{10} + \frac{3}{9}$

Comment: It depends. Is ordering important or not important? I don't think it is. If it isn't, this means you should use combinations instead. (Also note that your answer can in any case not be correct, because after drawing the first green ball, there are only 2 green balls left and not 3).

Comment: I suspect that this is the answer that you need (although it depends on how you interperet the question, as I just pointed out): $P(0.5<X<5)=P(X=1)+P(X=2)=\frac{{{3}\choose{1}}\cdot {{7}\choose{1}} + {{3}\choose{2}}}{{{10}\choose{2}}}\approx 0.533$

Answer (score 1):

When you pick two balls, you can get $0,1,$ or $2$ green ones.  You are asked for the probability that the number of green ones is between $0.5$ and $5$, which will be the case if you get $1$ or $2$ green ones.